# Why is this JS variable working inside my PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a JS script inside a PHP file wrapped in script tags, and for some strange reason, is working fine.

I usually would assign  JS variables to PHP through AJAX, but I tried this by mistake and it works fine. Any ideas why?

```
$(document.body).on("change","select[name=city]", function(){ 
    var v = $(this).val().replace("%","");
    if( v != "undefined" && v != undefined ){
    <?php $options['tax'] = v; ?>
    }
});
```

EDIT: So later on after a click event i'm displaying that php variable through JS, and displays the correct value.
which makes no sense to me.

EDIT: So when I assigned the v to the php variable, its like its assigning a constant, then
when I output it on JS with console $eshopoptions['tax'] it throws the 'v' which it interprets as the javascript variable.

Comment: What is `$options['tax']` used for later?

Comment: gets assigned to a session variable

Comment: Quantum? That really shouldn't work since PHP variables begin with a dollar sign.

Comment: `v != "undefined" && v != undefined` ???

Comment: I know it shouldn't work, thats why I'm asking the question, its actually working on my end.

Comment: @Ignacio: You will have to give us a reproducible example. At the moment, all we have to work with is skepticism.

Answer (score 8):

It's not working. The php is invalid.

```
<?php $options['tax'] = v; ?>
                        ^---this is an undefined constant in PHP.
```

Just because `v` happens to appear in both the JS and PHP doesn't mean they're the same variable. They're not. Remember, PHP executes on the server, and has NO CLUE what javascript is, or how to parse/execute it. Same for Javascript. It has no idea what PHP is, and never even SEES php code, as the php code is **GONE** by the time the JS engine fire up in the client browser.

What you're doing is assigning the undefined constant `v` to `$options['tax']`. PHP is polite and assumes you've forgotten to put quotes around a string, so it treats the code as

```
<?php $options['tax'] = 'v'; ?>
                        ^-^--
```

since this code doesn't actually output anything, the browser will see:

```
if (v != "undefined" && v != undefined) {
}  // <-- look ma, no php!
```

Comment: do a `view source` on your page in a browser. you'll see there's nothing in that if() block. it's not "working". it's simply not throwing any errors, because there's nothing fundamentally wrong with any of this, other than the lack of quotes on the `v`. In fact, php should throw a notice when that bit of code is executed.

Comment: I understand, but I am using that variable later, and it has the correct JS value, which is weird

Comment: @Ignacio It's not `v` that has a value assigned to it in the bad line. So `v` will work just fine in your Javascript. It's `$options['tax']` which is corrupted (it contains the string `'v'`).

Comment: using the variable where? in php? or in js? Are you sure it's not just a coincidence? there is absolutely no way that your JS code could set a PHP variable, UNLESS you're doing an ajax call and have a method in place to set that variable in PHP to begin with.

Comment: So turns out this:  console.log( <?=$options['tax']?>); turns into this console.log ( v ); That's why its showing the right value :/